# run parts of codemirror logic on server

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I am making small and simple tool to allow multiple users, write in the same codemirror based editor through node.js and socket.io server.

To achieve that i have on server:

```
let body = [];

socket.on("change", function(op) {
  if (
    op.origin == "+input" ||
    op.origin == "+insert" ||
    op.origin == "paste" ||
    op.origin == "+delete" ||
    op.origin == "undo" ||
    op.origin == "redo"
  ) {
    body.push(op);
    socks.forEach(function(sock) {
      if (sock != socket) sock.emit("change", op);
    });
  }
});
```

Then on client side:

```
this.editor = CodeMirror(this.panel.current, config);

Socket.link.on("change", data => {
  this.editor.replaceRange(data.text, data.from, data.to, "ignore");
});

this.editor.on("change", (i, op) => {
  Socket.link.emit("change", op);
});
```

This allows exchange information between clients and apply changes on editors, but then if we will use editor to write for example typescript, we will need to compile it. But on server side we only have array of instructions that codemirror gives. Is there a way to assemble a string on server side, just the same as client editor does? so then on some button click i can for example compile assembled string?